# Stored grid Option does not apply the specific styles

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am working on a feature where in the user could customize the grid (adding, grouping, sorting,aggregation etc) and then can save this as a template.

I am able to retrive the grid options on a button click as below.

```
JSON.stringify($scope.gridOptions)
```

however when I am using that as the grid option the grid loads but the grouping, sorting and aggregate is missing. if I analyze the grid option, I still have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ui-grids Save and restore functionalities.
[Save and Restore](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/208_save_state)

1. Inject 'ui.grid.saveState' module.
2. Add 'ui-grid-save-state' to your grid html.

```html
<div id="gridSaveState" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-save-state class="grid"></div>
```

Then you can use store the ui-grid states by saving the formatted JSON and also restore from that data.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I was missing the key word in the div which was causing it. Wandering if I can store aggregation as well? Column level aggregation? That object is coming blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case you can use the built-in save and restore state feature of angular-ui-grid. This will mean the grid will bring back the settings you want and display them correctly. You can also control which of these settings (e.g. sorting, filtering etc) are restored, and which not.

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/208_save_state

Some example code

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

    // I store when the user changes a filter, but you could
    // instead store on the user clicking a button or any other event
    $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function() {
        var state = gridApi.saveState.save();
        SomeServiceOfMineForStoringStuff.storeState(state);
    });
}
```

Later...

```
var savedState = SomeServiceOfMineForStoringStuff.getState();

if (savedState) {
    $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore($scope, savedState);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I certainly didnot look at this article. But for some reason my  $scope.gridApi.saveState is coming undefined. I have injected the 'ui.grid.saveState' into my app. $scope.gridApi looks OK.

Comment: What version of angular-ui-grid are you using?

Comment: HI, I use ui-grid - v3.1.0

Comment: OK, that should have it. Did you add the attribute to your HTML? See step 2 in the answer below.